# PHP: How to loop from 100 to 0 by -2 without letting it go infinitely?

Tags: php, loops

what I am trying to achieve here is to be able to loop from 0 to 100 (100, 98, 96, 94 ...) but has to stop at 0. What is doing right now is it passes 0 and -2 -4 which crashes the server. What am I doing wrong?

```html
 for ($i = 100; $i <= 100; $i--){
    echo $i--; 
    echo "<br>";
  }
```

Comment: `for ($i = 100; $i <= 0; $i-2){`?

Comment: `$i <= 100` is what stops the loop continung, your logic is wrong here

Comment: It was a typo.. edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe a little explanation would be useful.

The middle part of the for loop `$i <= 100` is what makes it infinite. That expression is checked before each iteration of the loop, and the loop will continue as long as that expression evaluates to true.

Since you set `$i`to 100 in the first section of the loop, and you're doing nothing except making it smaller, it will always be <= 100, forever.

The loop will work fine just the way you have it written if you change the continuation condition.

```
for ($i = 100; $i >= 0; $i--){
    echo $i--; 
    echo "<br>";
}
```

That way it will continue until `$i` is reduced to less than zero, then `$i >= 0` will be false, and the loop will end.

Comment: Thank you for a detailed explanation. It is more clear now!

Answer (score 2):

The third argument in for loop is what will be executed at the end of the loop. So:

```
for ($i = 100; $i >= 0; $i -= 2){
    echo "$i<br>";
}
```

Will do the trick

As you can read here https://secure.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php

> At the end of each iteration, expr3 is evaluated (executed).

Comment: `$i - 2` doesn't change `$i`. You mean `$i -= 2`

Comment: Fixed the typo as suggested by Barmar

Comment: Shouldn't the middle part be `$i >= 0`

Comment: maybe echo $i also ? :-)

Comment: I think it's time for me to stop... :D
Thank you guys for the observation

Comment: for ($i = 100; $i >= 0; $i-=2){
    echo $i++; 
    echo "<br>";
  } 
Right now, I am getting 100 99 98...0 which is getting close...

Comment: `$i++` will add 1 to `$i`. Guess you don't want that

Comment: @YongJunJung do not do the `echo $i++` this will increment the value. Just `echo $i`

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively:

```
<?php
foreach(range(100, 0, -2) as $n) {
    echo $n;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
for ($i = 100; $i >= 0; $i-=1){
    echo $i--; 
    echo "<br>";
  }
```

I figured it out somehow. Has been studying JavaScript for a year; Loop is still confusing to me

Comment: why decrease the value by 1 twice ? instead of doing it in just one operation?

Comment: "I figured it out somehow." somehow? by reading the answer of Felippe Duarte and not giving him his due credit :(